# Formatting JSON view in SharePoint how to group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, grouping, view-formatting

Can I check, I have two columns: category and questions.

I want to group all the questions that are related to the category as a group.  Can I know how?

```
Category A   Questions 1, 2 3
Category B   Questions 4, 5, 6
```

What is the JSON Schema code as I am using view format in SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** using JSON view formatting as you cannot get the values from another rows/list items in JSON code.

You can only access the column values from the same list item/row like `[$AnotherColumnFromSameRow]`.

Where `AnotherColumnFromSameRow` is internal name another column from same list item/row. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Flow to generate a new list containing the information as you need but it wouldn't be easy.